# Выпадающее по клику подменю на мобильном

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, меню

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать подменю на мобильном, открывающееся по клику?

Имеется меню `ul` с пунктами `li`, содержащими ссылки `a`. В некоторые пункты вложены скрытые подменю `ul`.

Как сделать, чтобы при клике на ссылку появлялось подменю?

```
<div class="navi">
  <nav>
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="o-magazine.html">О магазине</a></li>
      <li><a href="katalog/catalog/">Каталог</a>
        <ul class="subs">
          <li class="first"><a href="katalog/1/">Подраздел 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="katalog/2/">Подраздел 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="stati/">Статьи</a></li>
      <li><a href="dostavka.html">Оплата и доставка</a></li>
      <li><a href="kontaktyi.html">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте информативности вашему вопросу: на что кликаем, как выглядит свернутым, как открывается и т.д.

Comment: Кликаем на "Каталог", как открывается - пока не важно, можно поверх остальных пунктов, можно сдвигать остальные пункты вниз

Comment: на jquery подойдет или нужен чистый js?

Comment: Любой рабочий вариант устроит

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При клике на ссылку, если внутри `li` есть `ul.subs`, блокируем переход по ссылке и раскрываем меню. В раскрытом меню при клике на "главную" ссылку переход на другую страницу происходит как положено.

```js
$('nav ul li > a').on('click', function(e) {
  var li = $(this).closest('li');
  if (li.find('ul.subs').length) {
    if (!li.hasClass('active')) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    li.toggleClass('active');
  }
});
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var div = $('nav ul li.active');
  if (!div.is(e.target) && div.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    div.removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

nav ul>li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

nav ul li>ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  background: #ccc;
}

nav ul li>ul li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

nav ul li.active>ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navi">
  <nav>
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="o-magazine.html">О магазине</a></li>
      <li><a href="katalog/catalog/">Каталог</a>
        <ul class="subs">
          <li class="first"><a href="katalog/1/">Подраздел 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="katalog/2/">Подраздел 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="stati/">Статьи</a></li>
      <li><a href="dostavka.html">Оплата и доставка</a></li>
      <li><a href="kontaktyi.html">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, подключив bootstrap, с помощью data-* атрибутов bootstrap:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navi">
 <nav>
     <ul id="nav">
     <li><a href="o-magazine.html">О магазине</a></li>
     <li class='dropdown'>
     <a href="katalog/catalog/"  class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>Каталог</a>
     <ul class="subs dropdown-menu">
     <li class="first"><a href="katalog/1/">Подраздел 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="katalog/2/">Подраздел 2</a></li>
     </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="stati/">Статьи</a></li>
     <li><a href="dostavka.html">Оплата и доставка</a></li>
     <li><a href="kontaktyi.html">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

На мобильном работает, проверял лично.